# In java how can I extract camera related information from an image?

Tags: java, macos, metadata, photo

I am looking to extract the camera related information from a jpg using Java. I have looked around but have not been able to find a solution to my problem. I am exporting my photos from Aperture on my mac (OS X 10.7) and want to use the data from Aperture that is available in the file info.

Any ideas?

I am looking to have Dimensions and Key Words extracted from photos like this one: 80.167.88.49/masters/test.html. Currently i get an exception when trying to use the Metadata Extractor. I don't know if Aperture is adding information that cannot be handled but it throws an exception on all photos from Aperture.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/adobe/xmp/XMPException
    at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.extractMetadataFromJpegSegmentReader(Unknown Source)
    at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at ImageScaler.main(ImageScaler.java:141)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adobe.xmp.XMPException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 5 more
```

Code:

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    File image = new File("/Users/peterla/Desktop/P8214462.jpg");

    Metadata metadata = null;
    try {
    metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(image);
    } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Directory directory;

    // Keywords
    directory = metadata.getDirectory(IptcDirectory.class);
    String keywords[] = directory.getStringArray(IptcDirectory.TAG_KEYWORDS);

    // Dimensions
    directory = metadata.getDirectory(JpegDirectory.class);     
    String height = directory.getString(JpegDirectory.TAG_JPEG_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    String width = directory.getString(JpegDirectory.TAG_JPEG_IMAGE_WIDTH);     
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Metadata Extractor](http://drewnoakes.com/drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) has a simple interface for reading several types of metadata from many digital image formats. This includes the [EXIF](http://exif.org/) metadata format used in jpeg images. The library has good Javadoc style [documentation](http://metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Javadoc/index.html).

The primary entry point into the library is the [ImageMetadataReader](http://metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Javadoc/com/drew/imaging/ImageMetadataReader.html) object.

The [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/wiki/GettingStarted) page has a nice intro, including a nice example of how to get a value for a specific tag from EXIF format metadata.

**Update: Example for Extracting Keywords and Dimensions**

```
Directory directory;
// Keywords
directory = metadata.getDirectory(IptcDirectory.class);
String keywords[] = directory.getStringArray(IptcDirectory.TAG_KEYWORDS);

// Dimensions
directory = metadata.getDirectory(JpegDirectory.class);     
String height = directory.getString(JpegDirectory.TAG_JPEG_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
String width = directory.getString(JpegDirectory.TAG_JPEG_IMAGE_WIDTH);
```

**Alternatives**

Alternatives include the builtin java [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) library and [Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/sanselan/).

Comment: It is really great. Very easy to implement with the examples but i am having difficulties getting it to work on my photos. I think Aperture might add more information than the extractor can handle. I am looking to have Dimensions and key words extracted from photos like this one: http://80.167.88.49/masters/test.html

Comment: @Peter Larsen I added some example code for extracting Dimensions and Keywords. I tested it on your example picture and it works for me. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I don't know what is going on but i keep getting the following error on the same image that you have tested on.

Comment: @Peter-Larsen If you're using the latest version of the library, make sure you have both the jar for it and it's dependent library in your classpath.

Comment: ...dependent library :) the xmpcore was the problem. Thank you so much for your help. Everything is now working as expected. You have been a big help, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need a library to read the [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) metadata. There's an example of how to do it with ImageIO on this [blog post](http://www.barregren.se/blog/how-read-exif-and-iptc-java-image-i-o-api).

There are other libraries that you might also want to consider depending on your needs. For example [MetadataExtractor](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) or [Sanselan](http://www.fightingquaker.com/sanselan/).

Answer (score 1):

[`jhead`](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/), a JPEG EXIF header manipulation tool, is another option.