# Basic Image Information in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151230/in-java-how-can-i-extract-camera-related-information-from-an-image)

My requirements are very simple and straight - retrieve the basic information from a image(mostly, JPEG) - camera model, ISO etc.

I need some light-weight(small no. of classes,easy api)libraries for it - I checked a few like Metadata Extractor. But I'm not sure if it serves my purpose.

Comment: have you tried any of the libraries that are returned when you search google for "java exif library"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In java how can I extract camera related information from an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151230/in-java-how-can-i-extract-camera-related-information-from-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

My apologies - my initial question had my answer !

[Metadata extractor](http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/wiki/GettingStarted) served my purpose though I would like to see more options.